# auto-width first of three columns by content

Tags: html, css

Maybe someone is able to help me:
I got three columns. The first column should get as much width as available. The second column should get the width that the content within it needs. The third column-width is fixed.

I prepared a fiddle with some content. To visualize what i want to get just take a look at the bottom row in the fiddle.

So taking a look at the first row, the second column should move straight before the right column and the first column get as much width as possible.

the css part:

```
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
}

.first {
  background-color: coral;
  float: left;
  min-width: 33%;
}

.second {
  background-color: lightblue;
  float: left;
}

.third {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  float: right;
  min-width: 25%;
}
```

the html part:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="first">xxxxx</div>
  <div class="second">yyyy</div>
  <div class="third">zzzzzzz</div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="first"> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
    <br>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  </div>
  <div class="second">yyyyyyy</div>
  <div class="third ">zzzzzz</div>
</div>
```

[link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5Loyhb6w/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

> Note: In class`.third` you can mention `fixed width` instead of
>   `min-width` as per your requirement.

Check demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5Loyhb6w/2/)

CSS:

```
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.first {
  background-color: coral;    
  flex: 1 0 0;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.second {
  background-color: lightblue;  
}

.third {
  background-color: lightgreen;  
  min-width: 25%;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

Comment: I just think .third should have a width instead of min-width since the column width is fixed according the description. With the current settings, when the content of the third column grows, the width increases.

Comment: @Gerard Thanks for the observation. Will mention it in my updated answer. I think the Many_Miles is smart enough to get an idea from the answer.